# How to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 Beta 2 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Final Release?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 18.04

Right now I am using Ubuntu 18.04 beta 2 (Bionic) and already change the repository to kartolo sby to upgrade my Ubuntu, but when I run this command :

I also already do :

```
sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade 

sudo do-release-upgrade or sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

and change the setting of software and update to find new release of Ubuntu and it's still show message that no new release of Ubuntu.

How can I upgrade my beta version to final release version ?

Comment: You should check output of `cat /etc/os-release`. If it does not contain "development version", then you are already have 18.04 LTS.

Comment: thank you N0Rbert, how it can be like that ? i am very confuse because i remember that 2 days ago i install the ubuntu 18.04 beta version 2

Answer (score 3):

I am in the same situation as you.

cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

So I think it is already updated, as N0rbert commented.

Comment: thank you and its already updated, how can it be like this ?

Comment: It seems that you already have final version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.